# How can I have my static image repeat in an OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers

I also have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ericg_off/pen/gOEeorQ).

The static image shows up where it is supposed to, before any scrolling of the map occurs.

[image: initial location]

However, if I scroll to the right or left to another copy of Washington DC and look at the same location, the static image is missing.

[image: scrolled right]

Most OpenLayers sources have a wrapX property that takes of this situation, but not `ol.source.ImageStatic`.

How can I resolve this problem?

```js
async function loadHeatmapData() {
  const kmzText =
    "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";
  const zipFile = new JSZip();

  await zipFile.loadAsync(kmzText, { base64: true });

  const imageFile = zipFile.file("doc.png");
  const data = await imageFile.async("arraybuffer");
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
  const kmlFile = zipFile.file("doc.kml");
  const kml = await kmlFile.async("text");
  const parsedKML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(kml, "text/xml");

  const north = parseFloat(parsedKML.querySelector("north").textContent);
  const south = parseFloat(parsedKML.querySelector("south").textContent);
  const east = parseFloat(parsedKML.querySelector("east").textContent);
  const west = parseFloat(parsedKML.querySelector("west").textContent);

  const imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
      attributions: "wash dc2",
      url: url,
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      imageExtent: [west, south, east, north]
    })
  });

  const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

  osm.setTileGridForProjection(
    "EPSG:4326",
    ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
  );

  const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });

  const map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [tileLayer, imageLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      center: [-77.0231007567732604, 38.902979974562264],
      zoom: 18
    })
  });
}

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);

loadHeatmapData();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.3.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.10.1/jszip.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll to another copy"? In the codepen when I move left/right the image follows, it is always at the same place...?

Comment: Zoom out to see the whole world. If you scroll to the right until you see the United States show up again or the third or fourth time, zoom in on that copy of the US to where the image should be and it won't be there.

Comment: There is an open ticket for this issue. I am seeking a solution until that ticket can be resolved. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7288#issuecomment-1921550260